# How can I ignore root JSON Element in go?

Tags: go

I would like to serialize the following JSON into a map[string]string with map["Name"] == "Value"

```
{
    "Item": {
        "tags": {
            "Name": "Value"
        }
    }
}
```

However, I want to not have to create a strut with one field for "item". Is it possible to ignore the root JSON element in go similar to Java/Jackson: `mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);`

The best I have so far is:

```
items := make(map[string]map[string]string)
items := items["Item"]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would make a small helper that will skip the root of the structure around the lines of:

```
func SkipRoot(jsonBlob []byte) json.RawMessage {
    var root map[string]json.RawMessage

    if err := json.Unmarshal(jsonBlob, &root); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    for _, v := range root {
        return v
    }
    return nil
}
```

Then use it like that :

```
json.Unmarshal(SkipRoot(jsonBlob), &items)
```

Full example here : [Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/8wwpwwX4TQ)

Comment: Off Topic, I see why you used a for loop to extract the value without knowing the field name in JSON but I am wondering if there is a cleaner way to do it rather than creating a for that only runs once.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no.
The `encoding/json` package doesn't have any feature allowing you to ignore the root element. The easiest way is to use those unwanted structs you mentioned:

```
type Root struct {
    Item Item
}

type Item struct {
    Tags map[string]string
}
```

Here is a full working example:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Root struct {
    Item Item
}

type Item struct {
    Tags map[string]string
}

var data = []byte(`{
    "Item": {
        "tags": {
            "Name": "Value"
        }
    }
}`)

func main() {    
    var s Root
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &s); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    tags := s.Item.Tags
    fmt.Printf("%+v", tags)
}
```

**Output**

> map[Name:Value]

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/GJCCHuP1d0)